# How does the feval parameter influences the XGBoost training process?

Tags: xgboost, model-evaluations

In the package XGBoost, is possible to modify the feval (evaluated function) to a personalized one (as shown in the link: [MAPE eval metric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882724/mape-eval-metric-in-xgboost)).

I would like to know how is the training process of the XGB with a different evaluation function.

Is it very different? It really has a big influence? In which step this function matters?